# Launch app store to a specific app listing

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

my app requires the user to have Apple Pages installed. If it is not installed, i launch the app store to have them install pages. Is there anything i can append to the "com.apple.AppStore" bundle id to have it open to the app store Pages listing.

this is the web url for Pages on the app store 
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pages/id409201541?mt=12

```
if let appStoreURL =  NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.AppStore") {             
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(appStoreURL)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func itunesClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let access = "macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id"
    let appIdee = "409201541"
    let more = "?mt=12"
    let str: String = access + appIdee + more
    if let urlStr = URL(string: str) {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(urlStr)
    }
}
```

If you want to post a review...

```
@IBAction func itunesClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let access = "macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id"
    let appIdee = "409201541"
    let more = "?action=write-review&mt=8"
    let str: String = access + appIdee + more
    if let urlStr = URL(string: str) {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(urlStr)
    }
}
```

Comment: great. Thank you!